# Open SqlCeConnection and don't persist changes

Tags: .net, sql-server-ce

I need to create some temporary tables to make some queries within an application. I've noticed that I cannot create a complete temporary database using SqlCe so I've created a data model with the designer.
My application will use this data model only to load table structure. Then, the data will be used only when the application is running and won't be persisted.
The problem I have is that I cannot use mode = Read Only because it I've got an exception when I want to add rows.
Is there a way to open the database read-only and write changes somewhere in the %temp% directory?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add rows to any table, the database cannot be read-only